# Fedora19: YUM glibc is a duplicate of glibc

Tags: yum, fedora

I'm using Fedora 19, when I'm trying to perform a `yum update`, I get the following error.

*yum update:*

```
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Resolving Dependencies
There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction, or "yum history redo last", first to finish them. If that doesn't work you'll have to try removing/installing packages by hand (maybe package-cleanup can help).
--> Running transaction check
---> Package autocorr-en.noarch 1:4.1.0.4-6.fc19 will be updated
...
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:3.10.3-300.fc19 will be erased
---> Package kernel-devel.x86_64 0:3.10.3-300.fc19 will be erased
---> Package kernel-modules-extra.x86_64 0:3.10.3-300.fc19 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-2.17-11.fc19.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.17-11.fc19
           Removing: glibc-common-2.17-11.fc19.x86_64 (installed)
               glibc-common = 2.17-11.fc19
           Updated By: glibc-common-2.17-14.fc19.x86_64 (updates)
               glibc-common = 2.17-14.fc19
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-4.fc19.x86_64 (fedora)
               glibc-common = 2.17-4.fc19
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
glibc-2.17-14.fc19.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-2.17-11.fc19.x86_64
glibc-2.17-14.fc19.x86_64 has missing requires of glibc-common = ('0', '2.17', '14.fc19')
```

What I don't get, is that it says it's missing glibc-common-2.17-14 but if I do `yum info glibc-common-2.17` I get

```
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Installed Packages
Name        : glibc-common
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.17
Release     : 11.fc19
Size        : 114 M
Repo        : installed
Summary     : Common binaries and locale data for glibc
URL         : http://www.gnu.org/software/glibc/
License     : LGPLv2+ and LGPLv2+ with exceptions and GPLv2+
Description : The glibc-common package includes common binaries for the GNU libc
            : libraries, as well as national language (locale) support.
```

Available Packages
Name        : glibc-common
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.17
Release     : 14.fc19
Size        : 11 M
Repo        : updates/19/x86_64
Summary     : Common binaries and locale data for glibc
URL         : http://www.gnu.org/software/glibc/
License     : LGPLv2+ and LGPLv2+ with exceptions and GPLv2+
Description : The glibc-common package includes common binaries for the GNU libc
            : libraries, as well as national language (locale) support.

Which says that it is, indeed available. Does somebody know how to get out of this?
I allready tried to perform `yum clean all` and `yum-complete-transaction` but without any change.

thanks
Martin

Comment: I think the problem is that 2 versions of `glibc` are installed at the same time, while having only the old `glibc-common`. Try `rpm --repackage -e glibc-2.17.14.fc19` (reinstall using the rpm created under `/var/spool/repckage`if that doesn't work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed a very important warning message:

> There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running `yum-complete-transaction`, or "`yum history redo last`", first to finish them. If that doesn't work you'll have to try removing/installing packages by hand (maybe package-cleanup can help).

It looks like a previous package update was interrupted. You should use `yum-complete-transaction` to finish it, before attempting to do anything else.

If that fails, you can try repairing things manually by removing the database entry for the partially updated package, then updating again.

```
rpm -e --nodeps --justdb glibc-2.17-14.fc19.x86_64
yum update
```

Comment: He did mentionned trying `yum-complete-transaction`

Comment: `rpm -e --nodeps --justdb glibc-2.17-14.fc19.x86_64` then `yum update` did it, thanks guys